# Sampling without replacement from a given non-uniform distribution in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, random, multinomial

I'm looking for something similar to `numpy.random.choice(range(3),replacement=False,size=2,p=[0.1,0.2,0.7])`
in TensorFlow.

The closest `Op` to it seems to be `tf.multinomial(tf.log(p))` which takes logits as input but it can't sample without replacement. Is there any other way to do sampling from a non-uniform distribution in TensorFlow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use [`tf.py_func`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func) to wrap `numpy.random.choice` and make it available as a TensorFlow op:

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
size = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
replace = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
p = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

y = tf.py_func(np.random.choice, [a, size, replace, p], tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(y, {a: range(3), size: 2, replace:False, p:[0.1,0.2,0.7]}))
```

You can specify the numpy seed as usual:

```
np.random.seed(1)
print(sess.run(y, {a: range(3), size: 2, replace:False, p:[0.1,0.2,0.7]}))
print(sess.run(y, {a: range(3), size: 2, replace:False, p:[0.1,0.2,0.7]}))
print(sess.run(y, {a: range(3), size: 2, replace:False, p:[0.1,0.2,0.7]}))
np.random.seed(1)
print(sess.run(y, {a: range(3), size: 2, replace:False, p:[0.1,0.2,0.7]}))
print(sess.run(y, {a: range(3), size: 2, replace:False, p:[0.1,0.2,0.7]}))
print(sess.run(y, {a: range(3), size: 2, replace:False, p:[0.1,0.2,0.7]}))
np.random.seed(1)
print(sess.run(y, {a: range(3), size: 2, replace:False, p:[0.1,0.2,0.7]}))
```

would print:

```
[ 2.  0.]
[ 2.  1.]
[ 0.  1.]
[ 2.  0.]
[ 2.  1.]
[ 0.  1.]
[ 2.  0.]
```

Comment: Using `tf.py_func` is terrible since calling python operation slows computation down extremely. Especially if you are using GPU, then utilization can drop from 100% to 5% depending on a task. Because I think of no new op that can do that, the best is to write custom c++ op.

You can however hack it for example by iteratively sampling one element from an array, and removing that element by something like `tf.gather`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is. See [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9260) and [here](https://timvieira.github.io/blog/post/2014/08/01/gumbel-max-trick-and-weighted-reservoir-sampling/) for some background information. The solution is:

```
z = -tf.log(-tf.log(tf.random_uniform(tf.shape(p),0,1))) 
_, indices = tf.nn.top_k(tf.log(p) + z, size)
```