# Randomly selecting elements from a tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Given a tensor whose shape is `Nx2`, how is it possible to select `k` elements from this tensor akin to `np.random.choice` (with equal probability) ? Another point to note is that the value of `N` dynamically changes during execution. Meaning to say that I'm dealing with a dynamically-sized tensor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sampling without replacement from a given non-uniform distribution in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43310075/sampling-without-replacement-from-a-given-non-uniform-distribution-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just wrap `np.random.choice` as a `tf.py_func`. See for example this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45661210/4282745). In your case, you need to flatten your tensor so it is an array of length `2*N`:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2]) 
size = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
y = tf.py_func(lambda x, s: np.random.choice(x.reshape(-1),s), [a, size], tf.float32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(y, {a: np.random.rand(4,2), size:5}))
```

Comment: When I try to run this, I get a `NameError: name 'size' is not defined` error from this line `print(sess.run(y, {a: np.random.rand(4,2), size:5}))`. Any idea the issue?

Comment: Using `tf.py_func` is terrible since calling python operation slows computation down extremely. Especially if you are using GPU, then utilization can drop from 100% to 5% depending on a task.

You can use `tf.multinomial` however that samples with replacement. To sample without replacement, you are probably out of luck because I think of no new op that can do that -- the best is to write custom c++ op.

You can however hack it for example by iteratively sampling one element from an array, and removing that element by something like `tf.gather`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where I wanted to subsample points from a pointcloud for an implementation of PointNet. My input dimension was `[None, 2048, 3]`, and I was subsampling down to `[None, 1024, 3]` using the following custom layer:

```py
class SubSample(Layer):
  def __init__(self,num_samples):
    super(SubSample, self).__init__()
    self.num_samples=num_samples

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.shape = input_shape #[None,2048,3]

  def call(self, inputs, training=None):
    k = tf.random.uniform([self.shape[1],]) #[2048,]
    bl = tf.argsort(k)<self.num_samples #[2048,]
    res = tf.boolean_mask(inputs, bl, axis=1) #[None,1024,3]
    # Reshape needed so that channel shape is passed when `run_eagerly=False`, otherwise it returns `None`
    return tf.reshape(res,(-1,self.num_samples,self.shape[-1])) #[None,1024,3]

SubSample(1024)(tf.random.uniform((64,2048,3))).shape

>>> TensorShape([64, 1024, 3])
```

As far as I can tell, this works for TensorFlow 2.5.0

*Note that this isn't directly an answer to the question at hand, but the answer that I was looking for when I stumbled across this question.*